# Return warnings as well as errors from Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm looking for a way to return non-fatal validation "warning" messages for display on a JSP form (in addition to the usual validation "error" messages).  These would be messages that allow processing to continue instead of blocking the completion of a task.

I'd like to use the existing Spring 4 MVC plumbing for this:   The `BindingResult` object, the Spring Validator interface, and the Spring `<form:errors />` tag.   But so far I haven't been able to work out the details of returning a second BindingResult object and getting the messages to display.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
myFormValidator.validate(myForm, bindingResult);
myFormValidator.validateWarnings(myForm, warnings);
model.addAttribute("warnings",warnings);
return new ModelAndView(FORM_VIEW, "myForm", myForm);
```

But I have no idea how to tie the free-floating BindingResult object `warnings` to a `<form:errors />` tag on the JSP side.   Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's an easy way to do this using the existing `<form:errors />` tag.   What I wound up doing was creating a custom tag, based off of ErrorsTag.java and its superclasses.

Here is how the tag looks:

`<mytag:warnings bind="${warnings}" path="myFieldName" />`

This will list all the warnings for `myForm.myFieldName`  in a nicely styled block.

Here are the guts (boilerplate can be obtained from http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/AbstractHtmlElementTag.html ):

```
protected boolean shouldRender() throws JspException {
    try {
        if (this.getPath() != null &&
                this.getPath() != "") {
            // Field errors
            return (this.bind.hasFieldErrors(this.getPath()));
        } else {
            // Global errors
            return this.bind.hasGlobalErrors();
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
        // Neither BindingResult nor target object available.
        return false;
    }
}

protected int writeTagContent(TagWriter tagWriter) throws JspException{
    if (shouldRender()) {
        return doWrite(tagWriter);
    }
    return BodyTag.SKIP_BODY;
}

protected int doWrite(TagWriter tagWriter) throws JspException {
    try {
        tagWriter.startTag(getElement());
        writeDefaultAttributes(tagWriter);
        String delimiter = ObjectUtils.getDisplayString(evaluate("delimiter", getDelimiter()));
        List<String> errorMessages = null;
        if (this.getPath() != null) {
            errorMessages = getFieldErrorMessages(bind.getFieldErrors(this.getPath()));
        } else {
            errorMessages = getGlobalErrorMessages(bind.getGlobalErrors());
        }
        tagWriter.appendValue("<ul>");
        for (int i = 0; i < errorMessages.size(); i++) {
            String errorMessage = errorMessages.get(i);
            tagWriter.appendValue("<li>");
            tagWriter.appendValue(getDisplayString(errorMessage));
            tagWriter.appendValue("</li>");
        }
        tagWriter.appendValue("</ul>");
        tagWriter.forceBlock();
        tagWriter.endTag();
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return BodyTag.EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
}
```

Comment: As a side note,  I needed something fast - I'm sure this can be improved.